# Ruby: Don't raise error on date.strftime() if date is nil

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, null

There's a case where I disagree raising error when method is called on `nil`.

It is `Datetime.strftime` method. Indeed, it is supposed to format the `Datetime` object into a string.

Then it would make sense to have

```
datetime = Time.now
datetime.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') # => '17-10-2014'
datetime = nil 
datetime.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') # => ''
```

Instead I always need to write:

```
datetime.strftime('%d-%m-%Y') if datetime
```

which is a pain.

I understand calling a method on nil could chain many unexpected behavior afterwards hence needs to be interupted, but in that case, I don't see much danger. A string is returned anyways, and the result is fairly logic: (empty_date).to_s => empty_string.

Can I avoid this behavior?

Comment: Why is your `datetime` set to `nil`?

Comment: Your argument makes no sense as you expect some quite generic `nil` would know about some unrelated methods like `strftime` and return an empty string by default as a result. What should return with other unknown methods like `collect`, `join`, `split`, `modulo`, `each` etc. ?

Comment: `datetime` is `nil` because it is an attribute to my activerecord model: `@user.updated_at.strftim('%d-%m-%Y')`

Comment: It *can be* `nil`, doesn't have to.

Comment: @AugustinRiedinger this detail is quite important. You should add a `ruby-on-rails` tag and edit your question accordingly.

Comment: Well I'm sure the same situation could occur without using Rails. But yeah, maybe a rails-only solution is more appropriate here.

Comment: This could be solved with a helper or a decorator (take a look at [Draper](https://github.com/drapergem/draper))

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I disagree with you.

A nil value that is having a method called on it, in unguarded code, is almost always an exception to normal program flow, or a condition that has not been adequately validated.

I don't see why your particular case here should be treated as an exception.  Your value is nil, and you are trying to call a method which does not exist.  QED.

Comment: I see your point. But then `strftime` should be a class method of `Datetime` so that we could call `Datetime.strftime(datetime,'%d-%m-%Y')` instead of `datetime.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`

Answer (score 1):

In the context of Rails, 6 years later, I would use the [`try`](https://apidock.com/rails/v6.0.0/Object/try) method, which uses this way:

```
datetime = Time.now
datetime.try(:strftime, '%d-%m-%Y') # => '25-02-2021'
datetime = nil 
datetime.try(:strftime, '%d-%m-%Y') # => nil
```

Comment: Or with a modern Ruby, safe navigation: `datetime&.strftime('%d-%m-%Y')`.

Comment: Did not know about this one. Very elegant! Love it.

Answer (score 0):

You can define strftime on nil:

```
class NilClass
  def strftime(_)
    ''
  end
end

puts nil.strftime('whatever').inspect
=> ""
```

Comment: This solves the problem, but raises the question - *why* should NilClass know about strftime?